# WatchOS 5 How to test complications in future times in WatchOS 5 as Time Travel has been removed?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, watchos-5, watchos-simulator

I have implemented the code for complications in my app and it seems to work fine for current day. I would like to test how the complications would change overtime in future and past. Time Travel feature has been removed in WatchOS 5, so I am curious how would I got about testing it now?

Comment: Maybe it is not the most elegant method, but you could simply change the system time (macOS) which will also affect the time of the iOS simulator. Worked fine for me to test complications at specific points in time.

Comment: @Akar changing the system time on my mac would only work if I restarted the simulator afterwards which sort of defeats the point of me wanting to test how complications change by time. I ended up downloading WatchOS 4 simulators and testing with time travel there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an "answer" or more of a work-around but I ended up downloading WatchOS 4 simulator to my Xcode. WatchOS 4 simulator works fine with iPhone XS simulator running iOS 12.

Not sure how this will work out in future though.